# shim specified file cannot load after optimized with r.js

Tags: optimization, requirejs

i have a following  requirejs configuration in my code:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
   // urlArgs: 'cb=' + Math.random(),
    deps:["config","app"],
    paths: {
      'jquery'    : 'jquery/jquery',        
      'jquerymobile.config' : 'mobile/jquerymobile.config',
      'jquerymobile': 'mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min' ,
      'underscore': 'underscore-amd/underscore-min',
      'backbone'  : 'backbone-amd/backbone-min',
      text: 'plugins/text'
    },
    shim: {
      underscore: {
        exports: "_"
      },
      'jquery'    : 'jquery',
      'jquerymobile.config' : ['jquery'],
      jquerymobile : {
            deps : ["jquery", 'jquerymobile.config']
       },
       backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery', 'jquerymobile'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
       }
   }
  });
```

inside jquerymobile.config file i have console log statement, which cannot be seen after optimization with following build profile (build.js):

```
({
  appDir: '../',
  baseUrl: 'js',
  dir: '../../dist',
  name: 'config',
  skipDirOptimize:true,
  fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build)\.js$/,
  excludeShallow: ['settings'],
  mainConfigFile: '../js/config.js',
  optimizeCss: 'standard',
  removeCombined: true,
  deps:["config","app"]
})
```

I have a feeling that r.js ignoring the shim, dependecies,\n
is there any workaround?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following way:

include your `jquerymobile.config` in main.js require dependencies list:

```
require(['app', 'jquerymobile.config', 'jquerymobile'], function(App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```